# How to parallelise a code inside a while using OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to parallelise the `heat_plate` algorithm but I am stuck at this bit of code inside my while:

```
while(1)
{
.....
.....

#pragma omp parallel shared(diff, u, w) private(i, j, my_diff)
{
  my_diff = 0.0;
  #pragma omp for 
    for (i = 1; i < M - 1; i++) 
    {
      for (j = 1; j < N - 1; j++)
      {
        if ( my_diff < fabs (w[i][j] - u[i][j]))
        {
          my_diff = fabs (w[i][j] - u[i][j]);
        }
      }
    }
    #pragma omp critical
    {
      if (diff < my_diff)
      {
        diff = my_diff;
      }
    }
}

....
....
}
```

Not only I can't get it to work in parallel it actually takes longer to finish

**Edit:**

The Program runs in parallel
.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenMP this data dependency:

```
for (i = 1; i < M - 1; i++) 
  for (j = 1; j < N - 1; j++)
    if ( my_diff < fabs (w[i][j] - u[i][j]))
        my_diff = fabs (w[i][j] - u[i][j]);
```

is typically solved using [OpenMP reduction feature](https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/%7Eeijkhout/pcse/html/omp-reduction.html), which in your case will avoid the `critical` region (after the parallel for) and, consequently, improve the overall performance of the parallelization. So if you apply that feature your code would look like the following:

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(u, w) private(i, j)
{
  #pragma omp for reduction(max:diff)
  for (i = 1; i < M - 1; i++) 
     for (j = 1; j < N - 1; j++)
        if ( diff < fabs (w[i][j] - u[i][j]))
             diff = fabs (w[i][j] - u[i][j]);
}
```

In turn you can merge both pragmas into one:

```
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(max:diff) shared(u, w) private(i, j)
  for (i = 1; i < M - 1; i++) 
     for (j = 1; j < N - 1; j++)
        if ( diff < fabs (w[i][j] - u[i][j]))
             diff = fabs (w[i][j] - u[i][j]);
```