# Why this piece of parallelized code with OpenMP is not working well?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to parallelize this piece of C code with OpenMP:

```
for (i = 0; i < openSetSize; i++) {
    tmpF = arrayCells[openSet[i]].f;
    if (tmpF <= arrayCells[openSet[best]].f && tmpF <= arrayCells[bestPath[0]].f){
        isThereBest = true;
        best = i;
    }
}
```

I tried this way:

```
#pragma omp parallel {
            
    int best_private = 0;
    #pragma omp for nowait
    for (int i = 0; i < openSetSize; i++) {
        double tmpF = arrayCells[openSet[i]].f;
        if (tmpF <= arrayCells[openSet[best_private]].f && tmpF <= arrayCells[bestPath[0]].f) {
            isThereBest = true;
            best_private = i;
        }
    }
            
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        if(best_private > best){
            best = best_private;
        }
    }
}
```

but the performance are not satisfactory at all (much more time spent with the omp version).

Does anyone have better hints? Or do know where I am wrong?
Thank you so much

Comment: As far as i can tell, you are not doing much in your loop. Depending on openSetSize, the overhead of creating and maintaining multiple threads might outweigh the benefit of parallelizing the loop.

Comment: Different 'threads' would be attempting to access the `best_private` scalar at the same time. Isn't there some special OMP code to signal that (and get round it)?

Comment: @AdrianMole: Since `best_private` is declared inside the `omp parallel` construct, every thread will have its own separate variable of that name, i.e. the variable is private to every thread. Therefore, it should not be a problem if several threads write to `best_private` at the same time, because they will not be writing to the same variable. However, in contrast to `best_private`, the variable `isThereBest` does seem to be shared between all threads, which could cause thread contention when several threads write to it at the same time.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yeah - I realized about the `best_private` a while after I posted that comment; also about the `isThereBest`. But, even within that OMP block (and the `critical` part), there will be overheads in resolving the contention; those overheads are likely to wipe out any speed-up due to parallel running of such a 'simple' loop.

Comment: @AdrianMole: The `omp critical` construct is executed outside the loop, so I don't think it should be a problem. It will only require every thread to acquire the mutex a single time.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I see is that all threads are writing to the shared variable `isThereBest`.

The simplest solution would be to you give every thread its own private version of the variable, just like you did with the variable `best`:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    bool isThereBest_private = false;
    int best_private = 0;

    #pragma omp for nowait
    for (int i = 0; i < openSetSize; i++) {
        double tmpF = arrayCells[openSet[i]].f;
        if (tmpF <= arrayCells[openSet[best_private]].f && tmpF <= arrayCells[bestPath[0]].f) {
            isThereBest_private = true;
            best_private = i;
        }
    }

    #pragma omp critical
    {
        if ( isThereBest_private ) {
            isThereBest = true;
        if ( best_private > best ) {
            best = best_private;
        }
    }
}
```

However, a cleaner solution would be to use the `reduction` clause instead, which makes the entire `omp critical` construct redundant:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(||:isThereBest) reduction(max:best)
for (int i = 0; i < openSetSize; i++) {
    double tmpF = arrayCells[openSet[i]].f;
    if (tmpF <= arrayCells[openSet[best]].f && tmpF <= arrayCells[bestPath[0]].f) {
        isThereBest = true;
        best = i;
    }
}
```

Using the `reduction` clause instead of an `omp critical` construct will likely also improve performance.

Comment: More problematic is the race condition of the variable best_private

Comment: @dreamcrash: How can a private variable have a race condition? As far as I know, race conditions are only possible on shared data?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that I missed that best_private is declared inside the parallel region

Comment: @dreamcrash: No problem. :-)

Comment: Btw a possible improvement (performance-wise and readability -wise), although it depends a lot on other factors, would be to use openmp reduce with the 'max' and the '&&' operators similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67549626/1366871

Comment: With a greater number of threads the critical might lead to thread lock contention, but again that would have to be profiled to be 100% sure

Comment: ** the "||" operator is this case xD

Comment: @dreamcrash: If the loop only runs for a few microseconds, then you are probably right that thread contention in the `omp critical` construct could be a problem. However, if it runs for several milliseconds or more, then I believe it should not be a problem. Either way, your recommendation of using the `reduction` clause instead of an `omp critical` construct probably is the cleaner solution.

Comment: @dreamcrash: I have now added a solution to my answer which uses the `reduction` clause instead of the `omp critical` construct. Hopefully I did not make any mistakes; this is the first time I am using the `reduction` clause.

Comment: Looks fine, but a small caviar you can merge both pragmas into #pragma omp parallel for reduction(||:isThereBest) reduction(max:best). The benefit (aside for conciseness) is that you avoid an extra implicit barrier  that exists at the end of each of those pragmas

Comment: @dreamcrash: Ah, yes, you are right. Thanks. Both OpenMP constructs were seperate due to the variable declarations. But now that I have removed the variable declarations, it makes sense to merge the constructs. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Looks pretty nice I would upvote again if I could :)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel thank you. Your first piece of code seems better, but it does not give any performance improvement. I tried on Linux VM (8 CPUs) and Linux VM (24 CPUs) and the time results are practically the same... How is it possible?

For the second piece of code (with reductions), it gives Segmentation Fault error and don't understand why

Comment: @afetch: Could you provide a [mre] for both cases? Please don't delete the original question, but add them as an update to the bottom of the question. You can also ask a new question and provide a link to it here.

Comment: @afetch: When you say that you did not get any performance improvement, how long did the `for` loop run? Several seconds? Or less than a millisecond? Note that it [takes a few microseconds to create a thread](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/measuring-context-switching-and-memory-overheads-for-linux-threads/), so if your loop only runs for a very short time, you will not notice a performance improvement.

Comment: @afetch: The reason I am asking for a [mre] is that, as far as I can tell, the problem is not in the code that I posted, so I am guessing it must be somewhere in the code that you are not showing.

Comment: I was wrong in adaptying your code in the program, now the reduction works fine (it is clearer than before), but it is not quicker. The serial version of the For loop runs for about 40 seconds, and the parallel (8 virtual CPUs) about 18 seconds. Which seems not a particularly great improvement... Not enough: the same code, on a 24 CPUs virtual machine, takes the same time (about 18-19 seconds)

Comment: @fetch: There does not appear to be many calculations performed in the loop, so the bottleneck is probably not the CPU, but rather memory bandwidth. On non-[NUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access) systems, the memory bandwidth must be shared between all CPUs. Therefore, if you want a significant speed increase, you will probably need to use a NUMA system, in which memory bandwidth is not shared between all CPUs.

Comment: @afetch: Another possible performance improvement would be to optimize the [memory access pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_access_pattern) of your program, to make it more cache friendly(i.e. to improve [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)). For example, sequential access is better than random access, and accessing small amounts of memory at once instead of large amounts of memory is also better, so that it can fit in cache. The level 1 CPU cache is much faster than main memory, so memory bandwidth would be less of a bottleneck.